# How to implement shortest path algorithm in Apache Age using Python and Cypher?

Tags: python, apache-age

I'm working on a Python project that uses Apache age as the graph database, and I need to find the shortest path between two possible nodes. How do I implement this using Python? The code for node creation and the graph structure is as follows:

```
# Python code to create nodes and relationships
from age import Age

age = Age()
node_a = age.create_node("City", {"name": "New York"})
node_b = age.create_node("City", {"name": "Los Angeles"})
node_c = age.create_node("City", {"name": "Chicago"})
node_d = age.create_node("City", {"name": "Houston"})

edge_ab = age.create_edge(node_a, node_b, "CONNECTED", {"distance": 2451})
edge_ac = age.create_edge(node_a, node_c, "CONNECTED", {"distance": 713})
edge_cd = age.create_edge(node_c, node_d, "CONNECTED", {"distance": 940})
edge_bd = age.create_edge(node_b, node_d, "CONNECTED", {"distance": 1375})

# Sample graph structure:
# New York --(2451)-- Los Angeles
#     |                |
#   (713)            (1375)
#     |                |
#   Chicago --(940)-- Houston
```

How can I find the shortest path from New York to Houston?

Comment: Checkout this python package https://pypi.org/project/apache-age-dijkstra

Comment: Does your use case allow for only being interested in paths of up to some maximum depth (say 3 stops) or do you need to evaluate all possible paths? The former is easy to express as a Cypher query. The latter can be done in Cypher but the efficiency will depend on the number of possible paths.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options from using algorithms such as Bellmen-Ford to Dijkstra's algorithm. You can use the python package called [apache-age-dijkstra](https://pypi.org/project/apache-age-dijkstra/) which is an implementation of djikstra's algorithm as an implementation of the shortest path problem.

You can install it via PIP

```
pip install apache-age-dijkstra
pip install antlr4-python3-runtime==4.9.3
```

import the package

```
from age_dijkstra import Age_Dijkstra
```

Connect to postgresql

```
con = Age_Dijkstra()
con.connect(
    host="localhost",       # default is "172.17.0.2" 
    port="5430",            # default is "5432"
    dbname="postgresDB",    # default is "postgres"
    user="postgresUser",    # default is "postgres"
    password="postgresPW",  # default is "agens"
    printMessage = True     # default is False
)
```

Get all the vertices

```
nodes = []
for x in con.get_all_vertices():
    nodes.append(x['property_name'])
```

Create adjacent matrices using the edges

```
init_graph = {}
for node in nodes:
    init_graph[node] = {}
for edge in edges :
    v1 = edge['v1']['vertices_property_name']
    v2 = edge['v2']['vertices_property_name']
    dist = int(edge['e']['edge_property_name'])
    init_graph
    init_graph[v1][v2] = dist
```

Initialize the graph and then use the djikstra algorithm and print it

```
#init graph
from age_dijkstra import  Graph
graph = Graph(nodes, init_graph)

#use djikstras algo
previous_nodes, shortest_path = Graph.dijkstra_algorithm(graph=graph, start_node="vertices_property_name")

#print shortest path
Graph.print_shortest_path(previous_nodes, shortest_path, start_node="vertices_property_name", target_node="vertices_property_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point, there is no Pre-defined function in Apache-age to find the shortest path between two nodes, But you can define a Python function that finds the shortest path between the nodes,

Something like this:

```
def dijkstra(age, start_node, end_node):
      // function logic here
      return path_list
```

Or you can use the already defined functions defined by libraries such as NetworkX, igraph or PyGraphviz

Answer (score 0):

To find shortest path between nodes in a graph you can rely on using graph search algorithm. One such algorithm is Dijkstra's Algorithm thats works at starting at initial node  and finding the shortest path to all other nodes in a graph.

We can have Breadth First Algorithm

```
def bfs(age, start_node, end_node):
//logic here
return

startNode = node_a
endNode = node_d
shortestPath = bfs(start_node, end_node)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the shortest path between two nodes you have to implement a general graph shortest path finding algorithm.
Some of the popular algorithms:

- Dijkstra's Algorithm
- Bellman Ford Algorithm
- Floyd Warshall Algorithm

Now by following any particular algorithm, the graph traversal and computation can be written inside a function:

```
    def find_shortest_path(graph_name,start_node,end_node):
      //algo here
```

Now the function can return both the shortest distance and the path by backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

Since AGE models after a relational database, to find the shortest path you can choose an algorithm that works on a graph model.
The most popular algorithms are:

1. Dijkstra's Algorithm
2. Bellman Ford
3. Floyd Warshall Algorithm
4. A* Algorithm

In my opinion, for such a graph you should use the A* algorithm. It will follow the same coding structure as the above and will use the distance value as the heuristic. A pseudocode of this approach can look something like this:

```
def a_star(source, dest, heuristic):
    open_set = []
    closed_set = []
    g_score = [source, 0] #Of the starting heuristic node
    parents = None
    
    while open_set:
      current = min(open_set)[1]
      open_set.remove() #The distance of the current node from our destination node
      if current == dest:
        path = []
        while current:
           path.append(current)
           current = parents[current]
        return path[::-1] #Return in reverse order
      closed_set[current_node] = True

      #Add further logic here for how to treat neighbours
```